# How does CocoaPods stores pod zip links in different versions?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a private CocoaPods framework, because it is a iOS framework, I have to zip it and put into s3 to be able to download.

At the end it looks something like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name         = "XXX"
s.version      = "1.0.1"
s.homepage     = "https://bitbucket.org/XXX"
s.summary      = "XXX"
s.description  = "XXX"
s.license      = "Commercial"
s.author       = "XXX"
s.source       = { :http => "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/XXX.zip" }
s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"
s.swift_version= "4.1"
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = "XXX.framework"
end
```

Every time I update my framework, I will zip a new `.framework` file then replace the downloadable zip file with exact same url: `https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/XXX.zip`.

After it's been uploaded, I do `pod push YYY xxx.podspec` to pushes the podspec into my another central pod spec repository.

What I am wondering is, if the developer who uses this framework update it from `1.0.0` to `1.0.1`. CocoaPods will download the latest `framework` from that exact same link. What if the developer wants to roll back to `1.0.0`? where/How does CocoaPod stores the old (all) versions of the zip?

Comment: Instead of link it to your zip, just link it to your git

Comment: @QuocNguyen it's a `framework`, linking git is not the way to go though.

Comment: What don't replace the previous version? Can't you keep it?

Comment: @Larme keep the zip file of every version separately?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Can't you have on your server `https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/XXX-1-0-0.zip`, `https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/XXX-1-0-1.zip` etc which are different contents of each version and so the podspec can point-out each needed version?

Comment: @Larme that's a valid solution! could you post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to host on your server the different versions of your framework, and so give the different podspecs:

Old version

```
s.version      = "1.0.0"
s.source       = { :http => "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/XXX-1-0-0.zip" }
```

Current version:

```
s.version      = "1.0.1"
s.source       = { :http => "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/XXX-1-0-1.zip" }
```

And so one

```
s.version      = "1.5.1"
s.source       = { :http => "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/XXX-1-5-1.zip" }
```

This way, when you use the podspec with `pod install`/`pod update` the developer will fetch the correct sources.

I gave a possible naming for them. Also, you could use the different for "pre-versions" not yet public, to avoid users to "download them" before hand by guessing the address.

Answer (score 0):

The versions of a CocoaPod w/ name `<PackageName>`  are cached here: `~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/<PackageName>`

Comment: hmm, what does this actually do? just for the private framework developer to get local packages? what if a remote user facing the issue I described?