# How to manage versions with binary library distributions in Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I have a library for iOS which I distribute as a `.framework` with binary included. I struggle to find a way to manage versions of the library. I need to be able to support multiple versions like `1.0.0`, `1.0.1`, `1.0.2` etc

```
s.source            = { :http => 'https://somedomain.com/MyLib.zip' }
```

How do I need to modify my `.podspec` file so I can have separate `.zip` file for each version of the library and multiple versions of course. Note that my library is not in a git repo and using git tags is not an option for me.

Comment: What about using `https://somedomain.com/MyLib-1.0.0.zip` ? Or in the path: `https://somedomain.com/1.0.0/MyLib.zip`? You see the idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does CocoaPods stores pod zip links in different versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618062/how-does-cocoapods-stores-pod-zip-links-in-different-versions)

Comment: @Larme that was one of my initial ideas to have multiple `.podspec` files each located in a separate location and have users change the path to the podspec in the Podfile like so ```pod 'MyLib', :podspec => 'https://somedomain.com/MyLib_1.0.0.podspec'
pod 'MyLib', :podspec => 'https://somedomain.com/MyLib_1.0.1.podspec'``` I was wodnering if there is a way to do it without having to support multiple podspecs?

Comment: At some point if you were all "git", you would have had a podspec with a tag version 1.0.0 , then a podspec with a tag version 1.0.1, etc. The files would exists in the git history. So you'd have multiple podspecs. It just' you don't see it. But, in the end, isn't your podspec in a git (just the podspec + some doc/readme?), so it will be the same.